# Centos shell command cannot run in crontab

Tags: python, linux, shell, cron

I installed a python package which running in shell, like:

```
 $python-package -input 1
```

I create a `run.sh` file to run it as follow

```
python-package -input 1
```

(Here, `python-package` represents my installed python package.)

I can run this `run.sh` file correctly in the shell, but if I run it by `crontab -e`

```
0 0 * * * /data/project/run.sh
```

An error raises,

```
/data/project/run.sh: line 1: python-package: command not found
```

Comment: Try adding the full path to `python-package`, as the OS user running the crontab might not have `python-package` in `$PATH`

Comment: The full path of `python-package` seems a directory.

Comment: See the **Common Problems** section of the [crontab-tag-info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info). Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your shell

```
$ python-package -input 1
$ which python-package
/path/to/python-package
```

Then use

```
/path/to/python-package -input 1
```

in `run.sh`